# Powershell Find and Replace Loop, OutOfMemoryException

Tags: powershell, recursion, replace, out-of-memory

I have a working powershell script to find and and replace a few different strings with a new string in thousands of files, without changing the modified date on the files. In any given file there could be hundreds of instances of said strings to replace. The files themselves aren't very large and probably range from 1-50MB (a quick glance at the directory I am testing with shows the largest as ~33MB).

I'm running the script inside a Server 2012 R2 VM with 4 vCPUs and 4GB of RAM. I have set the MaxMemoryPerShellMB value for Powershell to 3GB. As mentioned previously, the script works, but after 2-4 hours powershell will start throwing OutOfMemoryExceptions and crash. The script is 'V2 friendly' and I haven't adopted it to V3+ but I doubt that matters too much.

My question is whether or not the script can be improved to prevent/eliminate the memory exceptions I am running into at the moment. I don't mind if it runs slower, as long as it can get the job done without having to check back every couple of hours and restart it.

```
$i=0
$all = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.txt
$scriptfiles    = Select-String  -Pattern string1,string2,string3 $all
$output = "C:\Temp\scriptoutput.txt"

foreach ($file in $scriptFiles)

{

$filecreate=(Get-ChildItem $file.Path).creationtime
$fileaccess=(Get-ChildItem $file.Path).lastaccesstime
$filewrite=(Get-ChildItem $file.Path).lastwritetime

"$file.Path,Created: $filecreate,Accessed: $fileaccess,Modified: $filewrite" | out-file -FilePath $output -Append

    (Get-Content $file.Path) | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "string1", "newstring" `
                                                  -replace "string2", "newstring" `
                                                  -replace "string3", "newstring"
                           } | Set-Content $file.Path   

(Get-ChildItem $file.Path).creationtime=$filecreate
(Get-ChildItem $file.Path).lastaccesstime=$fileaccess
(Get-ChildItem $file.Path).lastwritetime=$filewrite 

$filecreate=(Get-ChildItem $file.Path).creationtime
$fileaccess=(Get-ChildItem $file.Path).lastaccesstime
$filewrite=(Get-ChildItem $file.Path).lastwritetime

"$file.Path,UPDATED Created: $filecreate,UPDATED Accessed: $fileaccess,UPDATED Modified: $filewrite" | out-file -FilePath $output -Append

$i++}
```

Any comments, criticisms, and suggestions welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: The string replacement examples you show.... are they are separate replacements or are you find 3 string and replacing them with the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Biggest issue I can see is that you are repeatedly getting the file for every property you are querying. Replace that with one call per loop pass and save it to be used during the pass. Also Out-File is one of the slower methods of outputting data to file.

```
$output = "C:\Temp\scriptoutput.txt"
$scriptfiles  = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.txt | 
    Select-String  -Pattern string1,string2,string3 | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path

$scriptfiles | ForEach-Object{
    $file = Get-Item $_

    # Save currrent file times
    $filecreate=$file.creationtime
    $fileaccess=$file.lastaccesstime
    $filewrite=$file.lastwritetime

    "$file,Created: $filecreate,Accessed: $fileaccess,Modified: $filewrite" 

    # Update content. 
    (Get-Content $file) -replace "string1", "newstring" `
        -replace "string2", "newstring" `
        -replace "string3", "newstring" | Set-Content $file   

    # Write all the original times back. 
    $file.creationtime=$filecreate
    $file.lastaccesstime=$fileaccess
    $file.lastwritetime=$filewrite 

    # Verify the changes... Should not be required but it is what you were doing. 
    $filecreate=$file.creationtime
    $fileaccess=$file.lastaccesstime
    $filewrite=$file.lastwritetime

    "$file,UPDATED Created: $filecreate,UPDATED Accessed: $fileaccess,UPDATED Modified: $filewrite" 
} | Set-Content $output
```

**Not tested but should be fine.**

Depending on what you replacements are actually like you could probably save some time there as well. Test first before running in production obviously.

I remove the counter you had since it appeared nowhere in the code.

Your logging could easily be csv based since you have all the object ready to go but I just want to be sure we are one the right track before we go to far.

Comment: Storing the creation time, unless you want to log it, is kinda pointless since it wont change.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'm running the script now and it seems to be working much better. Time will tell if it solves the OutOfMemoryException (which I believe it will). Ultimately, all of the timestamps are logged as evidence of the script performing the desired function. The script is going to be making sweeps across 5+ years of data once it is properly tested and vetted and the logged timestamps are just proof that it is doing what it is supposed to.

Comment: @jw1n5 How do you know it is running better?

Comment: I'm monitoring resource (working set) utilization and open handles on files in the test directory. Overall utilization is lower on the system than it was with the previous script and it seems to be processing the files slightly faster than the last version as well.

Comment: Note my _# Verify the changes_ code is inaccuracte since the objects were not updated. I honestly would just remove that part anyway as it seems redundant.

Comment: Technically, it *is* verifying the changes. The objects were stored for the file initially, the file was then modified, the original values were written back, then the values were stored from the object again, post modification. As mentioned, the fact that the values aren't actually changing might seem redundant but to those who want proof nothing is changing, the logic and values are important. If we remove the 'write back' for the values, they change. In any case, the script ran for 14 hours without any issues, processing over 3,000 files. Thanks for the quick response and simple solution!

Comment: Fair enough. If the value writing was successful, no errors, that would be enough for _me_.